# Uber API - requests endpoint cannot read read json

Tags: python-requests, uber-api

I am trying to generate a POST request for the *requests* endpoint in the following python code:

```
import requests
...
response = requests.post(
'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests',
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
params={"start_latitude":"37.334381","start_longitude":"-121.89432","end_latitude":"37.77703","end_longitude":"-122.419571","product_id":"a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d"})
data = response.json()
```

The access_token was obtained using request scope during authorization. The response json is :
{"message": "Unable to parse JSON in request body.", "code": "invalid_json"}

Need help in formatting the request properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem - had to replace the params field with a data field and wrap the dict with json.dumps() before sending it off.

Comment: Would you mind being more explicit with what this entails? Not a python programmer but running into the same issue when trying to access Uber's API from Cocoa Rest Client.

Comment: Replace params={<param-contents>} with data=json.dumps({<param-contents>})

Comment: Oh, so you need to decode the JSON and add that to the body of the request. I feel like Cocoa Rest Client should be doing this automatically. Not sure what's not working for me then...

Comment: @Awesome-o have you figure it out how to post param in Rest Client ?

Comment: @Jagdeep I can only include request params in the request URL to get the api to work. Having the request params as JSON in the body of a request doesn't seem to work as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks.  Could have taken a little while to figure out (but it didn't!) , thanks for your answer.