# "Unable to parse JSON" error from Uber API

Tags: json, ruby, api, oauth-2.0, uber-api

(Similar question but different language/implementation - [Uber API - requests endpoint cannot read read json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752215/uber-api-requests-endpoint-cannot-read-read-json))

I am getting the following error from trying to make a post request to the `/v1/requests` endpoint of the UBER API.

`{"message":"Unable to parse JSON in request body.","code":"invalid_json"}`

Here is my code:

`response = access_token.post('https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests', {params: {:start_latitude => 37.761492, :start_longitude => -122.423941, :end_latitude => 37.775393, :end_longitude => -122.417546}, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}})`

As you can see I am using the `[oAuth2 gem][1]` to make the API calls. How can I format the query so that the JSON is acceptable to the API? I can't seem to find any documentation that sheds light on this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not using the oauth2 gem correctly. See the top answer to this question [Ruby on Rails: how to use OAuth2::AccessToken.post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333286/ruby-on-rails-how-to-use-oauth2accesstoken-post)

The `body` parameter is for the body of a POST. You're using `params` which is for query parameters.